# add a field and update another in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

A query returns an array of objects from a collection.  I want to add a field to each of the objects in that array, and update another field in every object of the array.

Products array before update:

```
[{ _id: 58d895b8ffc0346230a43a89,
  event: 'Junior Girls 12s',
  group: 'nonpro',
  price: 50,
  day: 'Friday' },
 { _id: 59d895b8ffc0346230a43a89,
  event: 'Junior Girls 14s',
  group: 'nonpro',
  price: 50,
  day: 'Friday', }]
```

My code to update the array of objects:

```
//add the field and changed price if late fee applies
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].field = registered.frifield;
  console.log(products[i].field);
  if(settings.latefeeamt > 0 && settings.frilatefee === true) { 
     products[i].price += settings.latefeeamt; 
  }
  console.log(products[i]);
  console.log(events.friday);
}
```

How products array SHOULD look after update:

```
[{ _id: 58d895b8ffc0346230a43a89,
  event: 'Junior Girls 12s',
  group: 'nonpro',
  price: 60,
  day: 'Friday',
  field: 'Main' },
 { _id: 59d895b8ffc0346230a43a89,
  event: 'Junior Girls 14s',
  group: 'nonpro',
  price: 60,
  day: 'Friday',
  field: 'Main' }]
```

How can I get this to work?  It console.logs the correct field inside the loop, but I get the original array when it's done.

Comment: there are other related objects that can impact your result `settings` and `events`

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, Don't change the array you are iterating, it's bad practice.

You can use `map` : [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)

```
var array = products.map((element, index) => {
    element.field = registered.frifield;
    if(settings.latefeeamt > 0 && settings.frilatefee === true) { 
        element.price += settings.latefeeamt; 
    }
    return element
});
```

This should return an array, inside you will have the updated product list

Comment: this doesn't work for me, either.  If I console.log element.field on the line after it's assigned, it shows the field name 'Main' correctly, but if I console.log array at the end, it's the unchanged array.

Comment: are you loggin the `array` or the `products`? can you provide a screen shot just after you log it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i wasn't sure about this portion of code because settings isn't defined

```
if(settings.latefeeamt > 0 && settings.frilatefee === true) { 
  products[i].price += settings.latefeeamt; 
}
```

Here you have a code that works i change the condition depending on the day, you can update it depending on your specification hope it helps

```
var products = [{
    _id: '58d895b8ffc0346230a43a89',
    event: 'Junior Girls 12s',
    group: 'nonpro',
    price: 50,
    day: 'Friday'
},
{
    _id: '58d895b8ffc0346230a43a89',
    event: 'Junior Girls 14s',
    group: 'nonpro',
    price: 50,
    day: 'moday',
}];
console.log(products);
for(product of products) {
    product.field = 'Main';
    if (product.day === 'moday') {
        product.price = 30;
    }
}
console.log(products);
```

Comment: settings comes in above what I shared in the code, but it's set to 20 and false so the price would remain the same.  The problem I'm having is that I can't get the field to be set!

Comment: settings comes in above what I shared in the code, but it's set to 20 and false so the price would remain the same. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the field to be set! in your code wont update because you have an && operator this evalutates the 2 expressions to be true: (settings.latefeeamt) 20 > 0 and (settings.latefeeamt)false === true according to what you are saying above. to enter the condition settings.latefeeamt should be true hope it helps